# Page is Jumping back to Top after targeting the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Hello guys im using wordpress and i need to jump to the comments when the user is clicking a link. 
The single.php is opening in a new tab and its loading the page on the anchor (comment-id) but after that its always jumping back to the top of the page.

I Know its a problem with javascript (as its working well when i disable js) but im not sure where to find the peace off javascript i have to stop or to change on single.php. 
Has anyone an idea how and where to change the javascript. So that i can stay at the comment after clicking the link on a different page?

this is the target `<a name="comment'.$comment_ID.'" href="#comment'.$comment_ID.'" onclick="deletco('.$comment_ID.')">DELETE</a>`

and this is the link form the other page to the target on single.php

```
<a href="'.$commpostlink.'#comment-'.$commentid.'" target="_blank">'.$titlecomm.'</a>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Jumping to top -> page reload. Can you prevent it? Yes, but you need to post the relevant script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I encourage you to comment out your JS files one by one it test it out tell you find the responsible js file.

Another approach is, if its javascript issue, then you can do this with jQuery:

```
$('a.aCommentLinkCssClass').click(function () {
  var url = $(this).attr('href').text();
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

and add css class to your link:

```
<a href="'.$commpostlink.'#comment-'.$commentid.'" target="_blank" class="aCommentLinkCssClass">'.$titlecomm.'</a>
```

or if you want just JavaScript only:

```
<script>
   function goToFunction(url) {
      window.location.href = url;
   }
</script>
```

and in your html:

```
 <?php echo '<a href="'.$commpostlink.'#comment-'.$commentid.'" onclick="goToFunction("'.$commpostlink.'#comment-'.$commentid.'")" target="_blank">'.$titlecomm.'</a>'; ?>
```

Comment: thank you ali. do you know how to do this with proper javascript?

Comment: thanks mate. its working. but i also found the code who is doing the trouble it was in my themes scripts.js file - 
addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(
hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } this crabby bit of code.  thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
onclick="deletco('.$comment_ID.'); return false;"
```

Or inside the function itself add a return false; at the end. You need to prevent bubbling of the event.

Comment: thank u Jorge  but its unfortunately not working; its only always working when i disable javascript completely. but i need it for other stuff

Comment: hi. why is it not working? when you press that A you get to the top of the page with the address in the browser added "#comment-<id of clicked comment>", right?

Comment: Wait a minute. You have something else changing the position of the scroll. If the page opens in the right location (pointing and anchor) and then goes you have a javascript code somewhere that is scrolling to top.

Comment: thats right.its while pageload its jumping to the right position but than before stop loading its jumping back to the top it has nothing to do with the onclick="deletco('.$comment_ID.'); function cause when i remove it its not working either. there is some other js causing this. but i have no plan how to stop that. but thanks again

Comment: If you are using and IDE, you should be able to search in the entire project. If so, make a search in all JS for "scroll" and see what it turns out. Also, and the obvious way to go first if look for jquery on ready or jquery on load or similar functions. That's where the initial code is running. Read the code and find what is moving the scroll.